# Creating a sub-model from pre-trained model

Tags: keras, cnn, convolution, autoencoder, ensemble-modeling

I have a pre-trained model having the following architecture:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 256, 256, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 256, 256, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder (Sequential)            (None, 7, 7, 256)    3752704     input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Merged_feature_map (Concatenate (None, 7, 7, 512)    0           encoder[1][0]                    
                                                                 encoder[2][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
mnet_conv1 (Conv2D)             (None, 7, 7, 1024)   2098176     Merged_feature_map[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 7, 7, 1024)   4096        mnet_conv1[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 7, 7, 1024)   0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
mnet_pool1 (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
mnet_conv2 (Conv2D)             (None, 3, 3, 2048)   8390656     mnet_pool1[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 3, 3, 2048)   8192        mnet_conv2[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 3, 3, 2048)   0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
mnet_pool2 (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 1, 1, 2048)   0           activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)             (None, 1, 2048)      0           mnet_pool2[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                     (None, 1, 256)       524544      reshape_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 1, 256)       1024        fc1[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)       (None, 1, 256)       0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 1, 256)       0           activation_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                     (None, 1, 128)       32896       dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 1, 128)       512         fc2[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)       (None, 1, 128)       0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 1, 128)       0           activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc3 (Dense)                     (None, 1, 64)        8256        dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 1, 64)        256         fc3[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)       (None, 1, 64)        0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 1, 64)        0           activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc4 (Dense)                     (None, 1, 1)         65          dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 1, 1)         4           fc4[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)       (None, 1, 1)         0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 1, 1)         0           activation_6[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_2 (Reshape)             (None, 1)            0           dropout_4[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
```

I want to create a new model that takes a single input and extracts the features using the encoder layer. The encoder is a sub-model which has the following layers:

```
conv2d_1
batch_normalization_1
activation_1
max_pooling2d_1
conv2d_2
batch_normalization_2
activation_2
max_pooling2d_2
conv2d_3
batch_normalization_3
activation_3
conv2d_4
batch_normalization_4
activation_4
conv2d_5
batch_normalization_5
activation_5
max_pooling2d_3
```

What I have done is I loaded the model and created the sub-network as follows:

```
encoder = Sequential()
for layer in model.get_layer('encoder').layers:
    encoder.add(layer)

model = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=encoder(input_img))
model.summary()
```

And, the summary looks like:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 256, 256, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_1 (Sequential)    (None, 7, 7, 256)         3752704   
=================================================================
Total params: 3,752,704
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 3,752,704
```

What I want to achieve is instead of 'sequential_1 (Sequential)' I want the model summary should show all the layers instead.

Is there any way to achieve this?